# Owntracks version 2.1.3 (Android) with MQTT version 3.1 (Ubuntu 20.04)

Tags: ssl, mqtt, home-assistant

I recently migrated a Home Assistant (HASSIO) instance from Ubuntu 18.04 to Ubuntu 20.04. While setting up MQTT, I noticed that TLS security option for MQTT was set as "tlsv1" and MQTT broker was reporting this as an error while starting the service:

```
Error: Unsupported tls_version "tlsv1"
```

I had to change this to a supported TLS version and tlsv1.3 did the trick. In `/etc/mosquitto/conf.d/default.conf`:

```
tls_version tlsv1.3
```

MQTT broker is now up and working. However Owntracks client from Android Phone has trouble connecting to the MQTT Broker. It constantly shows SSL Handshake error.

Any idea what could be wrong? Do I need to update the certificates on Owntracks to support the new TLS version?

Answer (score 0):

After some head banging, it seems tls version 1.2 works fine without changing the CA certificates on the Android device. I tried all options - tlsv1.1, tlsv1.2 and tlsv1.3 and only tlsv1.2 seemed to work for now.

It also seems that TLS v1.3 is the most secure option and given a chance it should be used if possible. The only problem is that CA certificates are distributed across a number of my Android devices and this is more of a logistcs issue. However for the time being, below option in `/etc/mosquitto/conf.d/default.conf` works fine:

```
tls_version tlsv1.2
```

Hope this helps others facing similar problems.